# ruby .extend help needed

Tags: ruby

given

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts "foobar"
  end
end
```

I can do

```
String.extend(Foo)
```

and as a consequence do

```
String.bar # => "foobar"
```

Why doesnt this work?:

```
a = String.new
a.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for "":String
```

Is it because 'a' is now and instance and .extend only works against class methods? Why does it lose the 'new' functionality I have given String via .extend?

Comment: Why would the fact that you can do `String.bar` imply that you could do `a.bar`? Does the fact that you can do `String.new` imply that you can do `a.new`?

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a perfectly valid question and OP has clearly made some effort to understand this subtle topic.

Comment: @maerics: See sepp2k's comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby allows you to add methods from a Module to a Class in two ways: `extend` and `include`.

Using the module you gave:

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts "foobar"
  end
end
```

With `extend` the methods are added as *class methods*, and can be called directly on the class object itself:

```
class Bar
  extend Foo
end

Bar.bar # => "foobar"
```

Alternatively, you can call it outside of the class scope:

```
class Bar
end

Bar.extend Foo

Bar.bar # => "foobar"
```

`include` is slightly different. It will add the methods as *instance methods*. They are only callable on an instance of the class:

```
class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.bar # NoMethodError
a = Bar.new
a.bar # => "foobar"
```

The key difference was that we first had to make an instance `a`, before we could call the instance method.

As sepp2k noted, `extend` is can be called on any Object, not just Class objects. For example, you can go:

```
class Bar
end

a = Bar.new
a.extend Foo
a.bar # => "foobar"
```

However, `bar` will only be added to the single instance `a`. If we create a new instance, it you will not be able to call it.

```
b = Bar.new
b.bar # => MethodNotFoundError
```

Comment: It should be pointed out, that extend is a method of Object, not Module, and can in fact add (singleton) methods to any kind of object - not just modules and classes.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, class String is an object, and by doing String.extend(Foo), you create a singleton class for the String class object and include the module Foo in it (that means that you are adding class methods to the String class object, and so can call `String.bar`). Full stop.

`a.bar` doesn't work because there's no instance method bar.

No, you haven't given new to String via extend.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Object#extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-extend) method adds to the receiver the methods defined by the argument module.

You have to remember that the `String` class is itself an object (of type `Class`) and so when you call "extend" with it as the receiver, that *class object* (String) itself gets the new method.

So in your first example, `String.extend(Foo)`, adds to the String *class instance* the function "bar".  That is, "bar" is now an instance method of the *shadow class* (aka Singleton class), so the object `String` (which is a class) now has the method "bar".  This has roughly the same effect as adding a class method to the String class (e.g. `def String.bar; puts 'foobar'; end`), so it has no effect on *instances* of type String.